# Kendo grid editRow method: suppress popup

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I've to created a customised 'update' button for a Kendo Grid.

Basically, it programmatically puts the appropriate row into edit mode (using `editRow`), updates some fields to specific values (using `model.set`) and then saves the row (using `saveRow`).

It's working, but it displays the popup edit window as soon as the `editRow` method is called, which is slowing down the process and doesn't look good.

Is there a way to suppress the popup when modifying data programmatically? This is what I'm doing (there may be an alternative/better way to do this):

```
    columns: [
        ....
        { command: [{name: 'edit' }, {name: 'approval'}, {name: 'delrow'}] }
    ],
    dataBound: function() {

        grid.find('.k-grid-approval').click(function() {
            var row = $(this).parents('tr:first');
            var g = requisitions.data('kendoGrid');
            var data = g.dataItem(row[0]);
            var model = g.dataSource.getByUid(data.uid);
            g.editRow(row[0]);
            model.set('status', 'Pending');
            model.set('date_submitted', moment().toDate());
            g.saveRow();
        });
```

I suspect there's a better way to do this, but I don't know what it is. Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was right... there is a better way:

```
dataBound: function() {

    grid.find('.k-grid-approval').click(function() {
        var row = $(this).parents('tr:first');
        var g = requisitions.data('kendoGrid');
        var data = g.dataItem(row[0]);
        var model = g.dataSource.getByUid(data.uid);
        // g.editRow(row[0]);
        model.set('status', 'Pending');
        model.set('date_submitted', moment().toDate());
        // g.saveRow();
        // editRow and saveRow are not required -- just use dataSource.sync()
        g.dataSource.sync();
    });
```